# QBXML PriceLevelQuery Request to WebConnector

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I'm doing a QBXML PriceLevelQuery request.  I've tried multiple variations but no matter what I do the response is always to give me a full data dump of all PriceLevel records until the system times out.  It wasn't until I left something in the XML that should have literally thrown an error and it gave me the response that I realized it was ignoring everything inside the PriceLevelQueryRq tags.  I'll paste a couple of my attempts below. The first one is the one that should have thrown the error but did not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="7.0"?>
        <QBXML>
          <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <PriceLevelQueryRq requestID="7468" >
              <ItemRef> <!-- optional -->
                <ListID>800012AA-1384983897</ListID>
            </ItemRef>          
            </PriceLevelQueryRq>
          </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="7.0"?>
        <QBXML>
          <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <PriceLevelQueryRq requestID="7466" >
              <FromModifiedDate >2014-07-20</FromModifiedDate>
              <ToModifiedDate >2014-07-24</ToModifiedDate>              
            </PriceLevelQueryRq>
          </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="7.0"?>
        <QBXML>
          <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <PriceLevelQueryRq requestID="7464" >
              <NameFilter>
                <MatchCriterion >Contains</MatchCriterion>
                <Name >Allspice</Name>
            </NameFilter>               
            </PriceLevelQueryRq>
          </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>
```

Again, all three of these return all possible results with no filtering.  Can anyone see why?

Comment: What version of QuickBooks are you using? I tested this using QuickBooks Enterprise 14.0 R6 and they worked for me. I received a "There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks item &quot;800012AA-1384983897&quot; in the PriceLevel." error for the first request. I used the third request (but changed the name to be an actual price level name I have in the file) and only that price level was returned.

Comment: Enterprise Solutions Version 13 - Manufacturing and Wholesale.

Comment: I guess the other thing I could do is just take all of the records in bulk and parse through them in my program.  Is there a way to make it so that the WebConnector doesn't time out on a response?